# Chaining and splitting a QuerySet of objects from multiple models

Tags: django

I want to go from showing the latest 10 objects from one model to showing the latest 10 objects from that and another model, treating the objects differently depending on the model they come from.

I have gone from (abbreviated):

**views.py**

```python
latest_ModelA = ModelA.objects.order_by('-pk')[:10]
context = {'latest_10': latest_10}
```

to:

**views.py**

```python
latest_ModelA = ModelA.objects.order_by('-pk')[:10]
latest_ModelB = ModelB.objects.order_by('-pk')[:10]
latest_combined = list(chain(latest_ModelA, latest_ModelB))
latest_combined.sort(key=lambda x: x.id, reverse=True)
context = {'latest_combined': latest_combined[:10]}
```

But how do I then go from:

**index.html**

```python
{% for a in latest_ModelA %}
    <a href="/display/thingA/{{ a.id }}/">{{ a.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

to something like:

```python
{% for a in latest_combined %}
    {% if a.get_classname == "thingA" %}
        <a href="/display/thingA/{{ a.id }}/">{{ a.name }}</a>
    {% if a.get_classname == "thingB" %}
        <a href="/display/thingB/{{ a.id }}/">{{ a.name }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This feels wrong. Before I go deeper down this hole, can anyone propose a more elegant solution?

For reference:

**models.py**

```python
class ModelA(models.Model):
    (...)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)
```

Comment: Great answers, I will experiment with them and accept an answer after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the only difference in your desired rendering the URL? If so, I'd write a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method for both model classes - this is exactly the kind of situation the example there discusses.

In general, you want behavior that varies by class to be defined by the class, not by inspecting the class type in the template.

Comment: Ended up using almost exactly the reverse() example on that page.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the method to generate the url on the model that way each instance/class will know how to build its own url without needing a conditional

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   def get_special_link(self):
      return "/display/thingA/{}/".format(self.id)

class ModelB(models.Model):
   def get_special_link(self):
      return "/display/thingB/{}/".format(self.id)
```

or better yet use reverse